# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (10, 24)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import seed
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, MaxPooling2D, Activation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

seed(1)
tf.random.set_seed(2)
droprate = 0.5

dataset = pd.read_csv('filecounts.csv')
data = np.array(pd.get_dummies(dataset['counts']))

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(8, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu",input_shape=(12, 12, 10)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
...
model.add(Conv1D(4, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
...
model.add(Conv1D(1, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
...
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1)

train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.5)

model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train, epochs=100, batch_size=10)
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(test, verbose=0, steps=1)

print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

Comment: Please share the full error track. It is not clear if it happens on trains or test or on data reading.

Comment: What is the shape of `train`?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive?hl=id @alift here is the full error

Answer (score 0):

Conv1D expects input shape 3+D tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)`and output 3+D tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (new_steps, filters)` with or without `padding='same'`.

Error is due to Maxpooling2D expects 4D tensor with shape `(batch_size, rows, cols, channels)`.

Working sample code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras as keras

X_train = np.random.random((12,12,10))
y_train = np.random.random((12, 1))

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(8, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu",input_shape=(12, 10)))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(4, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(1, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 15)
```

**Output**

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 944ms/step - loss: 0.6914 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6900 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6885 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6870 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 0.6856 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6841 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 0.6828 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 0.6814 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6801 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 0.6789 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7eff56169810>
```